# Gitlab + Jenkins Multi-project задачи

Tags: gitlab, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

Имеется сервер с Gitlab и Jenkins.

Хочется получить следующую схему:

1. Кто-то создаёт в Gitlab репозиторий с `Jenkinsfile`.
2. Gitlab ставит в известность Jenkins о том что появился новый репозиторий.
3. Jenkins идёт в Gitlab и сканирует определённую группу на наличие новых репозиториев, и для нового автоматически создаёт задачу сборки.

В Jenkins установлены плагины `Gitlab` и `Gitlab Hook`.
Но вот в Gitlab я не смог найти сервис `Jenkins CI` (так именуется в документации Gitlab) с опцией Multi-project.

Видимо документация древняя, и этот сервис выпилили.

Как реализовать оную схему?

Comment: Вы не смогли найти сервис или саму опцию?

Comment: @andreycha ни того ни другого нет, по мануалу среди сервисов есть Jenkins CI а уже внутри урл и если не ошибаюсь токен + несколько опций среди которых и есть нужная мне Multi-project. В реальности облазил весь Gitlab но так и не нашёл ни того ни другого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Поддержка Jenkins CI включена [только в Enterprise Edition](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/7525) (GitLab EE).
2. Начиная с GitLab 8.3 опция multi-project [отсутствует](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html) (возможно, она стала включаться по умолчанию, этого я не знаю).